# Cant make my upload form work using 2 versions of jQuery despite jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have one webpage that has 2 different forms in it, the 1st one is for uploading pictures (and it's supposed to give the link of the freshly uploaded images), and the second one is a "regular" form that allows to add a product to the database, in which I use the links given by the 1st form. The problem is that I use bootstrap's jQuery, and the upload form uses the 1.7.2 version (no need to say, there are conflicts.)

Once I hit the "send" button, it's supposed to make a loading bar appear and show "100%", followed by the image URL, while the upload process is done in another file named 'upload.php'
The problem is, even though I used 'jQuery.noConflic();' it still continues to redirect me to upload.php where there's nothing to see, but I can't find the problem...

Here's the upload form :

```
<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Uploader une image</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
      <div id="progress">
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="percent">0%</div >
        <br />

        <div id="alerte"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="envoyer"></label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <button type="file" value="envoyer" id="formenvoyer" name="myfile" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here is the PHP file :

```
<?php
$output_dir = "img/";


if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
 //Filter the file types , if you want.
 if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
 {
   echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
 }
 else
 {
      //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

  echo "<p>Uploaded File :<br />http://grindhouseleather.esy.es/admin/img/".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]."</p>";
 }

}
?>
```

And here's the JS :

```
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{

var options = { 
beforeSend: function() 
{
    $("#progress").show();
    //clear everything
    $("#bar").width('0%');
    $("#alerte").html("");
    $("#percent").html("0%");
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
{
    $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
    $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');


},
success: function() 
{
    $("#bar").width('100%');
    $("#percent").html('100%');

},
complete: function(response) 
{
    $("#alerte").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
},
error: function()
{
    $("#alerte").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: Impossible d'uploader les fichiers</font>");

}

}; 

 $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

});
```

What did I miss ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: shouldn't need 2 versions of jQuery in the first place. Load one, before all other dependent plugins and code. If you do load 2 you aren't using noConflict correctly for that scenario. You need to assign one version to different variable name that isn't `jQuery`

Comment: I deleted the part where I loaded the 2nd jQuery version, so I deleted the noConflict line, but it still doesn't work. I checked, the jQuery used by Bootstrap is the 1.11 version

Comment: what errors are thrown? Is there any other use of `noConflict? Such as in a wordpress theme?

Comment: There's only one error in the page, in a file named sb-admin.js, that you get when you download an admin page template in the bootstrap website. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", but I didn't touch anything in it and everything except this upload form seems to work

Comment: but that error can be blocking your code also

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `jQuery` for `jQuery.noConflict();`. Change it to:

```
jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

The reason is:

```
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

The above code makes no difference.